# RegEx for URL ending with a query string

Tags: regex, url

I've been using Ensighten for tag management. The way it manages conditions (which pages the tracking scripts are deployed onto) is by using RegEx for the protocol, host and path separately.

Right now, my current condition looks a bit like this:

```
Protocol: ^(https?)$

Host: ^((www|www-qa)\.example\.com)$

Path: ^(/section-one/page/?|/section-two/page/?|/section-three/page/?)$
```

This works fine. However, I've been asked to add a URL ending with a query string, and that's where I'm having an issue.

Essentially, I need to also target a URL with the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/section-one/page?&var123=456
```

How do I edit my RegEx for the URL path to include this path?

```
/section-one/page?&var[any numbers, letters, symbols]
```

Note that for this /section-one/, I only want to target /page or /page +  a query string, no subpages. I don't want to target a *specific* query string. I also want the other pages already in my RegEx to remain included.

How do I write this expression? I have to stick to the "must match this RegEx" single-expression format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Improvement of what you've got:

```
^/section-(one|two|three)/page/?$
```

Backslash can generally escape the special meaning of a question mark, though it depends on flavor.

```
^/section-(one|two|three)/page/?($|\?)
```

This assumes that the `$` above is more than just a formality, i.e. that it matches the end of the URL.

If you need to use capturing parentheses to actually store the query string, the engine should give you the longest possible match for `.*` so that there is of course:

```
^/section-(one|two|three)/page/?($|\?.*)
```